# Как вывести 2 запроса LIKE в одну таблицу в разных столбцах?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Как вывести 2 запроса `LIKE` в одну таблицу в разных столбцах?

Есть таблица - **table**

В ней нужно сделать 2 поиска по 2 столбцам, но при этом чтобы была возможность искать сразу по двум столбцам

**Делаю первый поиск по 1 столбцу:**

```
SELECT `number` FROM `table` WHERE `number` LIKE "%3__" ORDER BY `number`
```

**Поиск по 2 столбцу:**

```
SELECT `string` FROM `table` WHERE `string` LIKE "%A__" ORDER BY `string`
```

**Пытаюсь объединить и вывести сразу 2 запроса:**

```
(SELECT `string` FROM `table` WHERE `string` LIKE '%A__' ) 
UNION 
(SELECT `number` FROM `table` WHERE `number` LIKE '%3__' ORDER BY `number`)
```

В итоге выводит оба результата в столбце `string`.
Нужно, чтобы выводило в столбце `string` результаты sring и `number` результаты number. Корректно отображалось, без лишних пустых полей.

Может это проще сделать не через `UNION`?

Comment: Насчет "пустых полей".Я о том,чтобы не получалось так - сначала выводятся записи в столбце string,а в столбце number напротив записей string пустые поля,под которыми уже идут результаты number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT case when number LIKE "%3__" then number end as number,
       case when string LIKE "%A__" then string end as string
  FROM table
 WHERE number LIKE "%3__"
    OR string LIKE "%A__"
```

Только остается проблема с сортировкой. Вы обе выборки хотели сортировать по своему полю. Как отсортировать итоговую выборку с обоими полями, сложно представить. Особенно интересен момент с записями, где совпали оба поля как из соотносить (в смысле порядка вывода) с записями в которых только одно из полей